# How to draw multiple objects with different variable y?

Tags: python, list, oop, pygame

I've made a class `Rack(object)` in my program, and the method `draw()` which draws my object on a screen. I need to draw 10 the same objects, but with different variable y (it have to increment by 60 with every next object).

I've tried to append every object in the list, and then increment variable y by

```
for i in list:
  i.y += 60
```

but program was still drawing the same object

My class and method:

```
class Rack(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width), 1)
```

Could you please show me the way?

Comment: What is `list` object here ? Remember you need to increment first once, second twice and so on.

Comment: `list` is a built-in function. You should not name list object `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop:

```
for i in list:
  i.y += 60
```

will find each object in `list` (please rename this to something like `my_list`) and add 60 to its y value.  This does not have the effect you want, it just moves every object 60 units over.  There are many ways to do this the way you want, here it one:

```
for n,i in enumerate(my_list): # I have renamed the list here
  i.y += 60*n
```

By using `enumerate` you get not only each element in your list (`i`) But also a count of which element you are on (`n`).  You can then use the `n` variable to ensure that different objects are moved by different amounts.